# Android Game Development Extension for Visual Studio Can't Find APK when using Flavors

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-ndk, android-agde

The Android Game Development Extension works for my project when there's only Debug and Release builds. But when I add Flavors, everything builds but Visual Studio can't find the APK in order to deploy it to device. How does one resolve this problem? Thanks.